# What is an acceptable website request duration per page?

Tags: php, performance, laravel, web

I'm building a site in Laravel, and I just started using the debug bar, which gives you some info regarding your request duration and memory usage. I'm curious what the best practices for target request duration? What is realistic? What is too high? Right now, most of my requests have a duration of somewhere in between 150-250ms. I can't seem to find any info anywhere as to what is acceptable.

Comment: Entirely my own opinion, but I consider 1 second to be my acceptability threshold. Anything over that, and it's too slow. Users are getting ever more impatient, so everything needs to be as quick as possible. And if that's not possible, give them some feedback, e.g. a progress bar, so they know something is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some [guidelines](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/response-times-3-important-limits/):

> - 0.1 second is about the limit for having the user feel that the system is reacting instantaneously, meaning that no special feedback is necessary except to display the result.
> - 1.0 second is about the limit for the user's flow of thought to stay uninterrupted, even though the user will notice the delay. Normally, no special feedback is necessary during delays of more than 0.1 but less than 1.0 second, but the user does lose the feeling of operating directly on the data.
> - 10 seconds is about the limit for keeping the user's attention focused on the dialogue. For longer delays, users will want to perform other tasks while waiting for the computer to finish, so they should be given feedback indicating when the computer expects to be done. Feedback during the delay is especially important if the response time is likely to be highly variable, since users will then not know what to expect.

If you'd like more information, consider posting a question on the [UX Stack Exchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Nice answer. Values are generally applicable for most of the users. However, for some areas that have slower broadband speed, the user can tolerate longer response times. On the other hand, large companies usually have their own Key Performance Index (KPI) for response time on website, DB, as well as App (if applicable). I was once in a telecom company, their KPIs for DB, Web and App are 0.1s, 0.5s and 5.0s respectively.